# how to determine the principal end of the relationship

Tags: c#, database, relationship, new-operator

I've recently started learning programming with C#

I've created two classes and the relationship between them
like so:

```
class mojoodi
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        public laptop laptop { get; set; }
        public provider provider { get; set; }
        public store store { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 class laptop
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public string company { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public mojoodi mojoodi { get; set; }
    }
```

then I tried to save an object of the `mojoodi` type to my database, like so:

```
            mojoodi m1 = new mojoodi() { laptop = l1, provider = pg, store = s1, price = 52000000 };
            db1.mojoodis.Add(m1);
            db1.SaveChanges();
```

when I run the program, I get an error that says, you have to determine the principle end of the relationship between `mojoodi` and `laptop`
but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Please provide screenshot of the error or the full error details.

Comment: This is more of a general database question. The principle 
is the one with the primary key. The dependent is the one with the foreign key. https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-types-of-relations/